# were <met><welcomed> by

Tags: vocabulary

The context ;

The soldier -Private potton- had just come back from Dunkirk.He was among the first two hundred soldiers to arrive home in England.

As the soldiers left the boat that had brought them across the Channel, they ***were met*** by several reporters.

The reporters were from The Times, the Evening News , the Daily Sketch and the Daily Express.

They had been sent from London to find out what had happened at Dunkirk.

A)''As the soldiers left the boat that had brought them across the Channel, they ***were met*** by several reporters.''

is the meaning ''meet'' in passive in the sentence above same with the verb ''welcome''

B)''As the soldiers left the boat that had brought them across the Channel, they ***were welcomed*** by several reporters.''

sentence a and sentence b in the same meaning?

Comment: They don't have the same meaning. They have different words and those words have different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

*Met* simply means that the reporters were waiting on the shore to speak to the soldiers.

*Welcomed* has more connotations: it would imply a cheerful, friendly meeting.  "Welcome!" is a friendly greeting that you say to someone when you are happy they have arrived, and you want them to feel comfortable staying.

Without more context, we do not know whether *welcomed* would be appropriate.  For example, maybe the reporters were waiting to ask them tough questions about why they had left their posts, in which case it might have been a very unfriendly meeting.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct but "welcomed" implies more of a cordial, friendly greeting, whereas "met" just implies the reporters met them but nothing about being welcoming or friendly.